# Link to sidebarMenu item from dropdownMenu

Tags: r, shinydashboard

Try to create link from `dropdownMenu` to `menuItem`

Want  when click on task in `dropdownMenu`select `menuItem`.

I have :
1)

```
sidebarMenu(
          menuItem(  "Main",tabName = "Add_data", icon = icon("plus-circle"), badgeLabel = "!", badgeColor = "red"),
            menuItem("Other",tabName = "other", icon = icon("plus-circle"))
        )
```

2)`dropdownMenu(type = "tasks", .list = list(notificationItem(icon = icon("users"), status = "info","link")))`

What i need to paste in `href` in `notificationItem` to make it?

Tried `href = "Add_data"` `href = "#shiny-tab-Add_data"`-- not worked.

May be there is way to add on click event to `notificationItem` and add to it `updateTabItems(`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find one way

creating notification item on server:

```
ddd=notificationItem(icon = icon("exclamation-triangle"), status = "danger",paste0("noti"))
```

then change tags

```
   ddd$children[[1]]=a(href="#shiny-tab-Add_data","data-toggle"="tab", "data-value"="Add_data",list(ddd$children[[1]]$children))
```

## Update

there is problem with such method ( not work after navigation)

for other variant [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35796170/5018792)